# C/C++ header to java

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

Is there any good tool to generate java (+JNI support if needed) from a header file so that a C or C++ library can be used as-is. Kind of a reverse of javah. The real functionality would be in the C/C++, the Java would be only a shim on top for certain users.

I'm no expert on JNI but as far as I can see Javah forces you to do this back to front. It forces you to have JNI-isms penetrating unecessarily into the C code unless you write a conversion layer yourself. And writing a conversion layer by hand is basically a waste of time, since all the information is there in the header file to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C, you can use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). You do have to declare function signatures redundantly in Java, but do not have to write any glue code. JNA is very easy to use.

For C or C++, you can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). SWIG is a little more complex to use, but automatically generates Java wrappers for C++ classes. I'm enjoying it.

Comment: Thanks. After reading through the docs for both a bit. SWIG looks like it is probably the solution I need to use.

Answer (score 3):

[JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) does exactly that : it reads C/C++/ObjectiveC headers and outputs Java bindings that rely on [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) (C/C++), JNA (C only) or [Rococoa](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/) (ObjectiveC, uses JNA).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like SWIG works with Java: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html

Maybe this isn't exactly what you're looking for, though, since you do have to add SWIG directives…

Comment: SWIG is now at version 2. Your link is to 1.3.